# My array isn't being read properly on the server side socket

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I can read the array on the Client side. When I prepare to send the array through socket to the client, it's only printing the first element in the array and it's associated incremental number count. I have it print the array out in order successfully. Then I have the data variable, print out the array that is being sent through the socket. But it's only accepting the first element and string

Client:

```
from socket import *
import time
from datetime import datetime
##############################


array = ['January', 'Feburary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
         'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

##############################

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 29004
start_time = time.time()

##############################

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
print ('Socket created: ', TCP_IP)
clientSocket.settimeout(2.0)
clientSocket.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
print('Connected to Port: ', TCP_PORT)

###############################


a=0
b=0
#a=a+1



data_string = array[a] + " "+ str(a)
#a = a+1


#################
#Code now Prints the array in order.

#While loop, gets through array
while a < len(array):
#while a < len(data_string):
    #print('Sender sent a message: ', data_string)

    print('Sender sent a message: ', array[a])
    a += 1


#clientSocket.send(MESSAGE)
clientSocket.send(data_string)
data = clientSocket.recv(1024)


##########################
# Code does not print all the months. It's stuck on the first element.
#Seconds it took to execute
while b < len(data):
    print ("Data from Server: ", data + " Time: %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time) )
    b += 1

clientSocket.close()
```

Server:

```
from socket import *
import time
##########################

TCP_PORT = 29004
b = 0

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created.')

clientSocket.bind(('',TCP_PORT))
clientSocket.listen(1)

print('Server is ready')

##########################

while 1:
    connectionSocket, addr = clientSocket.accept()

    message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    while b < len(message):
        print('Receving data: ', message)
        b += 1

    clientMessage = message

    #clientMessage = message.upper()
    connectionSocket.send(clientMessage)

    connectionSocket.close()

    #my_array = pickle.loads(data_string)
```

Comment: `data_string` in client only contains first array element, the `send()` is after the loop, not inside.

Comment: @MichaelButscher why not make that into an actual answer?

Comment: @MichaelButscher how do I have set for all the elements? I know I have 'a=0', but how is it reading out the array just fine, but while it sends again to the server it's only the first element? I assume the 'send()' you are talking about is also in Client. I've moved it around and I'm still getting errors. The first array will begin to print, then crash

Comment: @bojack2424 If you get errors you should show them in the question along with the modified code that causes them.

Comment: @anarcat I guess that my comment mentions only a part of the problem.

Comment: @bojack2424 By the way: The `while b < len(message):` loop in your server only prints the same message a lot of times. This is probably also not desired. Maybe you should first gather more experience with programming with simpler tasks.